# What does adjustAdaptiveCoef error in logcat mean?

Tags: android, dalvik

I'm developing an android app, and sometimes get errors similar to the following:

> 11-21 16:03:15.219: E/dalvikvm(17170): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
>   11-21 16:03:16.212: E/dalvikvm(17170): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
>   11-21 16:03:17.649: E/dalvikvm(17170): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568

Does anyone know what they mean, or if they are of any concern?

Comment: What phone / Android version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems related to an `out of memory` condition of the Dalvik VM. The most frequent reason for this error to occur is when you (or the OS) is dealing with Bitmaps decoding.

Generally, you should not pay great attention to these errors if your app is not dealing with lots of images at a time (i.e.: a `GridView` of images).

Source: I was not able to find any official documentation.

EDIT: this is a typical stack trace that leads to an OutOfMemory error.

```
11-20 09:06:59.122: E/dalvikvm(6924): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
11-20 09:06:59.192: E/dalvikvm(6924): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=8388608, min=2097152, ut=256
11-20 09:06:59.452: E/dalvikvm(6924): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
11-20 09:06:59.483: E/dalvikvm(6924): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
11-20 09:06:59.483: E/dalvikvm-heap(6924): Out of memory on a 4088500-byte allocation.
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:472)
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:502)
11-20 09:06:59.503: E/AndroidRuntime(6924):     at com.myapp. ...
```

Comment: Hello,any of you had this issue in a Titanium Appcelerator app?